# show custom field image based on another Custom Field?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, if-statement, custom-fields

I have created a website for a car sales company and used Custom Fields. I have set a main (required) image and also another 9 for additional images.

This all works fine except that when all aren't used, it takes images from the next vehicle listing.

What I want it to do is to only show images based on each specific listing by using another custom field called `'ref'` as these are different for each vehicle. (e.g., HLM001, HLM002)

The code for each image is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php $image = get_field('vehicle_image2'); if( !empty($image) ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" rel="lightbox"</a><img class="img-responsive thumbs" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This can be seen at http://hleemotors.co.uk/vans/ when clicking `'View more details'`.

I'm ok with PHP but this has really stumped me. Any help would be great.

Comment: PHP is interpreted and rendered on the server, meaning that `if` statement is only being parsed once, before the user has seen the page or been able to interact with the form.

In order to achieve this dynamic form element, you'd have to use Javascript. Using the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library would probably be the easiest.

Comment: The 'ref' is within the same set of Custom Fields for each listing, is there no way it can only echo the images from that specific 'ref'? Basically, for all listings, if  an image is present for each 'vehicle_image2', 'vehicle_image3' etc, it shows that image for that 'ref'. But if it's empty, it shows images from the previous listing.

Comment: You just need to check the dependent field value first if it is set then you must go inside that condition and then fetch or show your required data. Well it depends how you have set the dependent condition in the backend.